# How to set a discordie discord bot to be playing a game?

Tags: javascript, bots, discord

I recently have been making a [discordie](http://qeled.github.io/discordie/#/?_k=qiwrz3) bot, and noticed that some discord bots say for example "Playing #help for help". I was wondering if there is any way todo that with discordie, and if not, if there is a way todo that with my bot which currently uses discordie. Thank you! I am using javascript if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use: client.User.setGame('#Help for help');

[Discordie documentation](http://qeled.github.io/discordie/?#/docs/IAuthenticatedUser?p=IAuthenticatedUser%23setGame&_k=gub66s)